# Regex for inserting - after specific indexes in a number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to insert '-' in a number. I want to insert this after the 3rd and the 7th letter.

For eg. Number : 123456789
Required Number : 123-4567-89

What I tried so far :

```
if (!Number.isNaN(value)) {
  val = value.match(/\d{3}(?=\d{2,3})|\d+/g).join('-');
}
```

This gives me the result '-' after every third occurrence and not the required one[i.e. 123-456-789]. Can some regex expert help with this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
val = value.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zlFX2W/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{3})` - [Capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1: three digits
- `(\d{4})` - Capturing group 2: four digits

The [`$1`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) stands for the Group 1 value (the first 3 digits) and the `$2` stands for the Group 2 value (the next 4 digits).

JS demo:

```js
console.log(
  "123456789".replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-") 
);
```

Comment: This works like a charm and the explanation is very clear. Thank you!